# Maven repository for QPid

Tags: java, maven, qpid

I am trying to use QPid as a JMS provider. Maven is used as a build tool. I cannot locate maven repository that contains QPid, so my build fails.

Questions

1. does somebody know mvn repository that contains qpid?
2. Is there a work-around? I have downloaded all JAR files and tried just to put them under .m2/repository/org/apache/qpid/qpid-common/0.6
   and
   .m2/repository/org/apache/qpid/qpid-client/0.6

But the build still fails. I believe I do not know maven enough to work on it. 
So, what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Unofficially: http://people.apache.org/~ebourg/qpid/maven/
- Officially: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/QPID-1916
- You can deploy them into your local/corporate repository.
- Or you can deploy it into the Sonatype OSS repo: https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide

Comment: I am stuck too with this problem, what solution do you suggest the best ?

Comment: should i downloaded from this line http://qpid.apache.org/download.cgi and put it manually in my repo ?

Answer (score 1):

In this [mailing list posting](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/qpid-users/201007.mbox/%3C4C374BF8.6010802@apache.org%3E) Emmanuel Bourg says he runs an unofficial maven repo for the qpid project at:

http://people.apache.org/~ebourg/qpid/maven/

However, these are effectively (if not in reality) snapshot releases, and there are risks in depending on snapshots published by someone else.  (Your code may break spontaneously due to some bug that has appeared in the snapshot that maven has just downloaded for you.)

Note that you *should* be able to manually add the POM and JAR files to your `.m2/repository` tree, but you have to follow the naming rules exactly.  The `mvn` command provides a better way to do this [using the `install` plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/specific-local-repo.html).

Comment: I discontinued the nightly builds at the address mentioned, the artifacts are now in the central repository.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that now, years after this question had been asked, QPid is available on Maven Central. Here's the coordinates of the broker...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
        <artifactId>qpid-broker</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Here the page on [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.qpid%22) listing all the modules QPid is made of.

Answer (score 0):

The Qpid artifacts starting with version 0.10 are now available from the central repository.

http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22org.apache.qpid%22